# limit jekyll posts to specified folder

Tags: jekyll, categories

I am using Jekyll to build a web site,

I want to have some folder structure like

```
root
   - _posts
       Kinds of MD files
   Index.html
   - v1.0
       - _posts
           Kinds of MD files
       Index.html
```

I want to build a web site, the URL like http://host/root/ points to current version document,the URL like http://host/root/v1.0 points to version 1.0 document.

In both index.html, I use code like below,

```
  {% assign sortedCategories = site.categories | sort %}
  {% for category in sortedCategories %}
  <h1 class="post-title" id="{{ category[1] | replace:' ','-' | replace:'.','' }}">{{ category[1] | join: "/" | upcase }}</h1>
  <ul class="post-list">
    {% for posts in category %}
    {% for post in posts reversed %}
    {% if post.title != null%}
    <li>
      <h2 class="post-title" id="{{ post.id | remove_first:'/'}}">{{ post.title }}</h2>
      <article class="post-content">
        {{ post.content }}
      </article>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  {% endfor %}
```

The issues I met is,

1. As both _post folder has similar posts and category, in the http://host/root/, each post is shown twice.
2. In URL http://host/root/, it has an additional category which contains all the posts (in both folder _posts and v1.0/posts)
3. The same issues for URL http://host/root/v1.0

I want to know how I can restrict the site.categories to only search specified folder? Or there is some other suggestions on this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`posts` can not be limited to a particular folder as it is site wide. You can create custom [`collection`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/). Suppose if you have v1, v2 and root(pointing to v2). You can use the same collection name for v2 and root.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @ganesshkumar, use jekyll collections for this

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please elaborate on _how_ to use Jekyll collections to answer the question. Thanks.